# Survey report in SSRS

Tags: matrix, reporting-services, reporting

I have two tables Question and Person. After a Person takes Survey, the Person and question are entered in PersonSurvey table.

Question

Question1   Option1 Option2 Option3 Option4

---

Question2   Option1 Option2 Option3 Option4

PersonSurvey Table

Person1 Question1   Option2

---

Person1 Question2   Option3

---

Person3 Question1   Option4

---

Person2 Question1   Option1

---

Person2 Question2   Option2

---

Person3 Question2   Option3

I need to create a matrix report in SSRS that looks like:
Report
Question1   Option1 Option2 Option3 Option4

---

```
         1         1       0       1
```

---

Question2   Option1 Option2 Option3 Option4

---

```
          0        1        2       0
```

My questions is: how do I get all options for each question even though only some options are selected by each person?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to create a query that JOINs you question with all Options and then LEFT JOIN your PersonSurvey table with the results to that query and count the Options in PersonSurvey.

Unfortunately, your question data isn't all in one field so that would need to be UNPIVOTED.

It's a bit hard to explain so here's an example I created using your data.

```
SELECT 1 AS QUESTION_ID, '1Answer1' AS OPTION1, '1Answer2' AS OPTION2, '1Answer3' AS OPTION3, '1Answer4' AS OPTION4  
INTO #QUESTION 
UNION 
SELECT 2 AS QUESTION_ID, '2Answer1' AS OPTION1, '2Answer2' AS OPTION2, '2Answer3' AS OPTION3, '2Answer4' AS OPTION4  
UNION 
SELECT 3 AS QUESTION_ID, '3Answer1' AS OPTION1, '3Answer2' AS OPTION2, '3Answer3' AS OPTION3, '3Answer4' AS OPTION4  


SELECT 1 AS PERSON_ID, 1 AS QUESTION_ID, '1Answer2' AS ANSWER
INTO #PERSONSURVEY 
UNION 
SELECT 1 AS PERSON_ID, 2 AS QUESTION_ID, '2Answer3' AS ANSWER
UNION 
SELECT 2 AS PERSON_ID, 1 AS QUESTION_ID, '1Answer1' AS ANSWER
UNION 
SELECT 2 AS PERSON_ID, 2 AS QUESTION_ID, '2Answer2' AS ANSWER
UNION 
SELECT 3 AS PERSON_ID, 1 AS QUESTION_ID, '1Answer4' AS ANSWER
UNION 
SELECT 3 AS PERSON_ID, 2 AS QUESTION_ID, '2Answer3' AS ANSWER



;WITH QUESTIONS AS (
SELECT QUESTION_ID, OPTIONS, ANSWERS  
FROM #QUESTION 
UNPIVOT
(ANSWERS FOR OPTIONS IN (OPTION1, OPTION2, OPTION3, OPTION4 )) AS UNPVT
)

SELECT Q.QUESTION_ID, Q.OPTIONS, Q.ANSWERS, COUNT(P.ANSWER) AS ANSWERS 
FROM QUESTIONS Q 
LEFT JOIN #PERSONSURVEY P ON P.QUESTION_ID = Q.QUESTION_ID AND P.ANSWER = Q.ANSWERS
GROUP BY Q.QUESTION_ID, Q.OPTIONS, Q.ANSWERS
```

The resulting table matches the values you gave:

> **Q1** - 1 1 0 1
>
> **Q2** - 0 1 2 0

Now you can create your matrix with the **Question** as the Row Group and **Options** as the Column Grouping.

Comment: just got to the end of an almost identical answer :) Saved me a bit of typing ...

Comment: Thank you. I'll try on your answer and will get back to you.

Comment: When parameters are in use, the result set is back to the only that are submitted by person.

Comment: It sounds like you might be filtering after JOINing the Person Survey data to the Questions. You'll need to filter the person either in a subquery or in the JOIN's ON statement.

Comment: Yes, I was filtering after Join. As you've suggested, now I have filter on JOIN's ON statement but it showing not just the filtered data.

Comment: `LEFT JOIN P ON P.PERSON_ID = (@PERSON_ID) AND ...` should filter for just the person you want. Can you post your query in your question and I'll take a look.